# kafka-python : Getting error while specifying partition in kafka producer

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to insert data to different partition for same topic. I am using python-kafka 1.4.3 on a linux machine

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer() 
producer.send(topic='test', value=b'test', partition=1)
```

Getting error:
AssertionError: Unrecognized partition

Answer (score 0):

First, check what is the total number of partition of that topic.

Second, the partition count starts from 0.

```
producer.send(topic='test', value=b'test', partition=1)
```

The above code will insert the data in PARTITION 2.
If you want to insert data in partition 1 just do partition=0

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a topic with 2 partitions. It partition count starts from 0. So there will be two partitions 0 and 1.
2. When you do this, `producer.send(topic='test', value=b'test', partition=1)`, it basically means you are putting a MESSAGE in a TOPIC in PARTITION with INDEX 1.
3. So you can either create a TOPIC with 2 partitions then you can put data in partition with index 1. Or, you put partition=0 (by default there will be 1 partition for each topic).

Answer (score -1):

The most probable cause is that your topic has 1 partition, and partition numbers are starting with 0...

Comment: Is it possible to define that using python-kafka ??

Comment: What do you mean to define with python-kafka??? How many partitions you topic have?